# Precisão numérica no SQLite

Tags: sqlite

Sobre a precisão numérica no SQLite v3.20.0.
Veja a sequência de comandos abaixo e o resultado do .dump. O valor associado à declaração INSERT não é o mesmo valor obtido.
Insiro o valor 123456.789 e obtenho 123456.7890000000043. Como pode isso ocorrer?

```
SQLite version 3.20.0 2017-08-01 13:24:15
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
Connected to a transient in-memory database.
Use ".open FILENAME" to reopen on a persistent database.
sqlite> CREATE TABLE Teste (Campo Number(9,3));
sqlite> INSERT INTO Teste Values (123456.789);
sqlite> SELECT * From Teste;
123456.789
sqlite> .dump
PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE Teste (Campo Number(9,3));
INSERT INTO Teste VALUES(123456.7890000000043);
COMMIT;
sqlite>
```

Answer (score -1):

A matemática de ponto flutuante binário é assim. Na maioria das linguagens de programação (não somente no SQLLite), ele é baseado no padrão IEEE 754. Por exemplo, o JavaScript usa a representação de ponto flutuante de 64 bits, que é o mesmo que o dobro de Java. O ponto crucial do problema é que os números são representados neste formato, uma vez que um número inteiro tem uma potência de dois; números racionais (como 0,1, que é 1/10) cujo denominador não é uma potência de dois, não podem ser exatamente representados.
Seguem as referências: [Wiki - Representação Binária de Float](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)

Comment: Mais Tem Como resolver isso?

Comment: Nestes casos o melhor é tratar sem casas decimais, ou seja sempre como inteiro, e no momento de exibir o dados, faz a divisão, incluindo as casas decimais que deseja. Ex: 123,45 = 12345/100